# Get a simple MLP in TensorFlow to model XOR

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, xor, tensorflow

I tried to build a simple MLP with an input layer (2 neurons), a hidden layer (5 neurons) and an output layer (1 neuron). I planned to train and feed it with `[[0., 0.], [0., 1.], [1., 0.], [1., 1.]]` for getting the desired output of `[0., 1., 1., 0.]` (elementwise).

Unfortunately my code refuses to run. I keep getting dimensionality errors no matter what I'm trying. Quite frustrating :/ I think I'm missing something but I can not figure out what is wrong.

For better readability I also uploaded the code to a pastebin: [code](http://pastebin.com/GpH7WEEi)

Any ideas?

```
import tensorflow as tf


#####################
# preparation stuff #
#####################

# define input and output data
input_data = [[0., 0.], [0., 1.], [1., 0.], [1., 1.]]  # XOR input
output_data = [0., 1., 1., 0.]  # XOR output

# create a placeholder for the input
# None indicates a variable batch size for the input
# one input's dimension is [1, 2]
n_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])

# number of neurons in the hidden layer
hidden_nodes = 5


################
# hidden layer #
################
b_hidden = tf.Variable(0.1)  # hidden layer's bias neuron
W_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([hidden_nodes, 2], -1.0, 1.0))  # hidden layer's weight matrix
                                                                         # initialized with a uniform distribution
hidden = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W_hidden, n_input) + b_hidden)  # calc hidden layer's activation


################
# output layer #
################
W_output = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([hidden_nodes, 1], -1.0, 1.0))  # output layer's weight matrix
output = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W_output, hidden))  # calc output layer's activation


############
# learning #
############
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(output, n_input)  # calc cross entropy between current
                                                                          # output and desired output
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)  # mean the cross_entropy
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)  # take a gradient descent for optimizing with a "stepsize" of 0.1
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)  # let the optimizer train


####################
# initialize graph #
####################
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()  # create the session and therefore the graph
sess.run(init)  # initialize all variables

# train the network
for epoch in xrange(0, 201):
    sess.run(train)  # run the training operation
    if epoch % 20 == 0:
        print("step: {:>3} | W: {} | b: {}".format(epoch, sess.run(W_hidden), sess.run(b_hidden)))
```

**EDIT:** I am still getting errors :/

```
hidden = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(n_input, W_hidden) + b_hidden)
```

outputs `line 27 (...) ValueError: Dimensions Dimension(2) and Dimension(5) are not compatible`. Altering the line to:

```
hidden = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W_hidden, n_input) + b_hidden)
```

seems to be working, but then the error appears in:

```
output = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hidden, W_output))
```

telling me: `line 34 (...) ValueError: Dimensions Dimension(2) and Dimension(5) are not compatible`

Turning the statement to:

```
output = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W_output, hidden))
```

also throws an exception: `line 34 (...) ValueError: Dimensions Dimension(1) and Dimension(5) are not compatible`.

**EDIT2:** I do not really understand this. Shouldn't `hidden` be `W_hidden x n_input.T`, since in dimensions this would be `(5, 2) x (2, 1)`? If I transpose `n_input` hidden is still working (I even don't get the point why it is working without a transpose at all). However, `output` keeps throwing errors but this operation in dimensions should be `(1, 5) x (5, 1)`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(0)  It's helpful to include the error output - it's also a useful thing to look at,  because it does identify exactly where you were having shape problems.

(1)  The shape errors arose because you have the arguments to matmul backwards in both of your matmuls, and have the tf.Variable backwards.  The general rule is that the weights for layer that has `input_size, output_size` should be `[input_size, output_size]`, and the matmul should be `tf.matmul(input_to_layer, weights_for_layer)` (and then add the biases, which are of shape `[output_size]`).

So with your code,

```
W_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([hidden_nodes, 2], -1.0, 1.0))
```

should be:

```
W_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, hidden_nodes], -1.0, 1.0))
```

and

```
hidden = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W_hidden, n_input) + b_hidden)
```

should be `tf.matmul(n_input, W_hidden)`; and

```
output = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W_output, hidden))
```

should be `tf.matmul(hidden, W_output)`

(2)  Once you've fixed those bugs, your run needs to be fed a feed_dict:

```
sess.run(train)
```

should be:

```
sess.run(train, feed_dict={n_input: input_data})
```

At least, I presume that this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Edit 2 is wrong.  I'll edit my answer to point out all of the places that are backwards -- your tf.Variable declaration for W_hidden is also backwards.  They need to all be of the form `[InputLayerSize, OutputLayerSize]`.  So the first layer should be `[2, hidden_nodes]`.  The matmuls should be `input_layer x this_layer_weights`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is running. However, the network does not learn properly, all inputs generate an output of nearly 1.0. I guess something in my cross entropy is wrong..